# When a feature image is empty, my Android app is force stopped

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to create JSON REST API app in Android. The REST API has call from `WordPress REST API`. So I have shown the WordPress posts (title, feature image, description) in Android ListView with image and I have done this work. But I faced one problem, when many posts does not have feature images then while running the app, the app has stopped.

**Here is my code:**

**MainActivity.class code**;
this class has set the JSON REST API with model.

```
public void getRetrofit(){

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseURL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

RetrofitArrayApi service = retrofit.create(RetrofitArrayApi.class);
Call<List<WPPost>>  call = service.getPostInfo();

call.enqueue(new Callback<List<WPPost>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<WPPost>> call, Response<List<WPPost>> response) {
        Log.e("mainactivity", " response "+ response.body());
        mListPost = response.body();
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        for (int i=0; i<response.body().size();i++){
            Log.e("main ", " title "+ response.body().get(i).getTitle().getRendered() + " "+
                    response.body().get(i).getId());



            list.add( new Model( Model.IMAGE_TYPE, response.body().get(i).getId().toString(),  response.body().get(i).getTitle().getRendered(),
                    response.body().get(i).getExcerpt().getRendered().toString(),
                    response.body().get(i).getBetterFeaturedImage().getSourceUrl() )  );


        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<WPPost>> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});



}
```

**Adapter.class code**
 I have set the image, the image has shown when all post have feature image, but any post has not set image this time app has stop, the app has not working. I have set if else loop, this loop not work.

```
if(object.Image !=null && !object.Image.equals("")) {

            Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(object.Image)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .into(((ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).imageView);

        }else {

            Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .into(((ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).imageView);

        }
```

**Model.class**
 this model class for wordpress post

```
public class Model {

    public static final int IMAGE_TYPE =1;  
    public String id, title, subtitle, Image ;
    public int type;


    public Model ( int mtype, String mid, String mtitle, String msubtitle, String image  ){
        this.id=mid;
        this.title = mtitle;
        this.subtitle = msubtitle;
        this.type = mtype;
        this.Image = image;

    }
    public String getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public String getSubtitle() {
        return this.subtitle;
    }


}
```

Comment: what is the crash on logcat for this?

Comment: wait sir, my laptop too low

Comment: logcat not show anything

Comment: if app is crashing then there must be something in the logcat.. any exception or something

Comment: this is image showing problem. Actually image url is BetterFeaturedImage > SourceUr  from api. When have no image this time BetterFeaturedImage = null from api.. This is the problem

Comment: 11:52 PM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

11:53 PM Gradle build finished in 1m 38s 783ms

11:55 PM Can't bind to local 8700 for debugger

7/30/2018
12:00 AM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

12:02 AM Gradle build finished in 1m 50s 467ms

Comment: that seems you have opened debug tab. Click on logcat and run app again

Comment: Process: com.sk.searchtry, PID: 3981
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sk.searchtry.MainAc2$1.onResponse(MainAc2.java:96)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)

Comment: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: okk thats null pointer exception ... check response carefully ... some of parameters you are putting in mode are null

Comment: check the values for nullability which you are putting in the model class in `onResponse` method

Comment: know this null, The wordpress post have feature image, so api show this post feature image is better_featured_image > sourceurl = image.url. but post have no feature image, this time api show is better_featured_image = null

Comment: if(object.Image !=null && !object.Image.equals("")) {
            Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(object.Image)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .into(((ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).imageView);
        }else {
            Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .into(((ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).imageView);
        }

Comment: put a check on that if betterfeaturedImage is not null then catch its sourceurl otherwise directly put it null or empty string in the modelclass

Comment: use like this https://hastebin.com/otecaxalas.cs

Comment: object.image is " better_featured_image > sourceurl ".......... when no detect better_featured_image = null when no image

Comment: i just paste a small code ... replace it with your add to list item code and run it

Comment: thanks :-) many many thanks for your support .. Seriously this code is run successfully....