# How to use @path in retrofit request

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2, android-json

I  am using @path in retrofit request. Actually variable call other activity.
So i have try the @path request but it not worked . Please help me, how to solve this problem.

```
String CATE_ID = getIntent().getExtras().getString("cateid");

    private String baseURL = "http://www.example.com";

@GET("wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories={CATEGORY_ID}")
    Call<List<WPPost>> getCatPostInfo(@Path("CATEGORY_ID") String CATEGORY_ID);

  Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseURL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RetrofitArrayApi service = retrofit.create(RetrofitArrayApi.class);
        Call<List<WPPost>>  call = service.getCatPostInfo(CATEGORY_ID);
```

Comment: try `@Query` in the request

Comment: try this but not work

Comment: Any error in the logcat?

Comment: Can you share your api url and response hit on browser?

Comment: this is  Wordpress api url.

Comment: I have added an answer. do as I mention in answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try this**

**BASE URL**  http://www.example.com/

**Retrofit Interface**

```
 @GET("wp-json/wp/v2/posts")
 Call<List<WPPost>> getCatPostInfo(@Query("categories") Integer categories);
```

**Retrofit call**

```
 Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(baseURL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RetrofitArrayApi service = retrofit.create(RetrofitArrayApi.class);
    Call<List<WPPost>>  call = service.getCatPostInfo(CATEGORY_ID);
```

Comment: i have one more question ..please help me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51574389/when-a-feature-image-is-empty-my-android-app-is-force-stopped